# Sizeof &a vs *a

Tags: c, sizeof

I searched thoroughly but could not find the solution to this:
Assuming `sizeof(int) = 4`, we define:

```
int a[10] = {0};
```

What is the output of the following:
1. `sizeof(&a)`
2. `sizeof(*a)`
3. `sizeof(a)`

I know that `sizeof(a)` is equal to `sizeof(int) * 10 = 40`.
I also understand that `*a` is actually a the first element in the array, therefore `sizeof(*a)` is actually size of the `int` which resides in there, i.e. `4`.

However, after running the code, I do not understand why size of `&a` is `8`.
I know that the `'&'` operator returns the address of the variable `a`, but why the `sizeof` the address is `8`?

Comment: `&a` is an *address* which is `8` bytes if you run `IA-64` (`64` bit) and will be `4` in case of `x86` (`32` bit)

Comment: This isn't as trivial to explain as it may seem, definitely not a question you can expect a beginner to answer. There's various subtle crap involved, namely exceptions to the rule of array decay. Did you get the question from a C beginner-level teacher?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The size of the address depends on your architecture and is not directly related to the size of an `int` itself. So it’s 8 in your case, which seems pretty normal (64 bits).

Comment: I see, so it does not depend on the type of the array at all? We were not taught this .. Thank you Michael!

Comment: @Tegernako most systems use the same way of storing any address

Comment: Yep; it doesn't depend from the type. An address is just a number that points to a memory location, so it doesn't matter if it is an int, a bool or a struct: data will be placed in a cell of the memory that is identified with a number (the memory address).

Comment: @TheDeveloper that's not quite true on all systems, so it is better to not learn it like that. A pointer to `int` is a pointer to `int` and a pointer to `char` is a different thing, and they can be converted to each other.

Comment: Yep, but I was talking about what is an address, not about pointers in C.

Answer (score 4):

The key to understanding this is to know that arrays usually "decay" into pointers to the first element, whenever they are used in an expression. *Except* for some special cases. The rule of array decay and the exceptions are found in the C standard (C17 6.3.2.1/3):

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a
>   string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

As we can see, `sizeof` and `&` are exceptions to the rule.

This means that `a` in `sizeof(&a)` does not decay to a pointer. We can know this because `sizeof` and unary `&` are both unary operators with the same precdence, but with right-to-left operator associativity. Meaning that `&a` gets interpreted first and there is no array decay when `&` is used.

So we get the address of the array. In your case, the size of an int pointer of type `int(*)[10]`. What size a pointer got has nothing to do with the size of an `int`, but it is likely to be either 4 or 8 bytes on 32 and 64 bit systems respectively.

In case of `sizeof(*a)`, then just like in the `&a` case, the rigth-to-left associativity of unary operators means that `*a` gets interpreted first. And so the array does decay into a pointer to the first element, before `sizeof` is applied. So `*a` gives the size of the first element, which is the size of an `int`.

And finally in case of `sizeof(a)` there is no array decay since `a` is used with `sizeof` and no other operator is present. Meaning we get the size of the whole array.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe you should mention that operator precedence and associativity would only be relevant if OP didn't use parentheses. As the question is written, it is no doubt that & will be computed before sizeof. This would only be relevant for `sizeof &a` instead of `sizeof(&a)`

Comment: @klutt No, the parenthesis here is not a primary expression, but part of the sizeof operator syntax. The two cases of allowed syntax for `sizeof` is `sizeof unary-expression` or `sizeof ( type-name )`. But well, the right-to-left associativity of these operators is quite intuitive to understand regardless of that.

Comment: @Lundin: Yes, the parentheses in `sizeof(a)` or `sizeof(&a)` are a primary expression, not part of the `sizeof` operator syntax. The grammar for `sizeof ( type-name )` requires a type name, and `a` and `&a` are not a type names. `sizeof(a)` or `sizeof(&a)` only matches `sizeof unary-expression`. The automatic conversion of an array to a pointer does not occur because the specification of parenthesized expressions in C 2018 6.5.1 5 says “A parenthesized expression is a primary expression. Its type and value are identical to those of the unparenthesized expression…”

Comment: @klutt: You are correct that precedence and associativity are irrelevant; the structure of the expression is compelled by the nesting of the operations. For unary operators, the so-called precedence is relevant only when the operators are on different sides of an operand, as in `* a ++`, where there is nominally a choice between `(* a) ++` and `* (a ++)`. (“So-called” because the grammar actually resolves this; there is not a separate rule in C about precedence.) With `sizeof & a` or `* ++ a`, there is no way to bind the first operator to the operand without binding the second operator first.

Comment: @klutt: Associativity is not relevant because it is only a property of binary operations (and also is resolved by the grammar, not a separate rule).

Answer (score 2):

```
sizeof &a == sizeof (int (*)[10]) // pointer to 10-element array of int
sizeof *a == sizeof a[0] == sizeof (int)
sizeof  a == sizeof (int [10])
```

and just to be complete

```
 sizeof &a[0] == sizeof (int *)
```

All of these sizes depend on the underlying platform. Pointer type sizes do not depend on the size of the pointed-to type (there’s no relation between the sizes of an `int` and an `int *`).  Different pointer types may have different sizes - the only requirements are:

- `char *` and `void *` have the same size and alignment;
- pointers to qualified types have the same sizes and alignments as their unqualified equivalents (e.g., `sizeof (const int *) == sizeof (int *)`;
- all `struct` pointer types have the same size and alignment;
- all `union` pointer types have the same size and alignment;

On any modern desktop or server system you're likely to encounter (read: x86), all object pointer types have the same size and alignment.  Just be aware that there are oddball architectures out there where that may not be true.